# Finding web element using javascript statments through Python Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to find specific web element by executing javascript code and then click on that element. This is my code:

```
driver.get('https://justjoin.it')
driver.maximize_window()


for position in [x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="css-1x9zltl"]')]:
      javascript = f"document.evaluate('//div[contains(@class, 'css-1x9zltl') and text()='{position}']', document);"
      driver.execute_script(javascript).click()
```

And when I run this code console throws me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has to do with the interaction of the single and double quote marks within your f-string. Try escaping one by changing your `javascript` to:

```
javascript = f"document.evaluate(\"//div[contains(@class, 'css-1x9zltl') and text()='{position}']\", document);"
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks man, first part works perfectly. But I can't click the element ;/ Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @beginsql I'm afraid not; that is a straight selenium problem. You should probably post it as a separate question.